# How to use Application Insights or App Analytics for UWP Apps which is uploaded to Windows Store(Instead of using App Center)?

Tags: uwp

The following link explains on how to use App Center and Azure Application Insights.
[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/mobile-center-quickstart)

Whether it is possible to send analytics to Azure Application Insights?

Comment: Do you mean you want to send the log information directly from your app to the Application Insights without using App Center?

Comment: Please go to the Azure dashboard, and find the question mark button on the right top. Click it and then select the Help + Support button on the bottom. Then you could ask the Azure support team about this.

Comment: Yes, Need to send log information directly from your app to the Application Insights.